# Solving $x - \frac{1}{x} < 0.$

Tags: inequality

I need to solve for x: 
$$x - \frac{1}{x} < 0.$$
I realize that $x\neq 0$.

The following is always true: 
$$x-\frac{1}{x} < 0 \iff x < \frac{1}{x}.$$
If $x > 0$: 
$$x < \frac{1}{x} \iff x^2 < 1 \iff x < \pm 1$$
$$0<x<1$$
If $x<0$:
$$x < \frac{1}{x} \iff x^2 > 1 \iff x > \pm 1$$
$$-1<x<0.$$

So **my answer** is that $-1<x<1$ with $x \neq 0$. But this is not true. The **real answer** is $x<1$ and $0<x<1$. Why? Where is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to $x^2<1$ is not $x<1$ or $x<-1$, but rather $x<1$ and $x>-1$. Choosing the negative square root requires reversing the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer I was looking for. I'll skip using $x > \pm 1$ in the future and use $|x| > 1$ instead. Makes more sense.

Comment: Actually it would be x < 1 *and* x > -1 in this case. (*or* if x^2 > 1, however.) The absolute value is the only practical way.

Answer (score 3):

A step like $x^2>1\implies x>\pm1$ is terribly dangerous (and you got trapped).

$$x^2>1$$ is actually $$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)>0$$ solved by

$$(x>1\land x>-1)\lor(x<1\land x<-1)$$

which simplifies to

$$x>1\lor x<-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the second case: In fact, $x^2 > 1 \Leftrightarrow (x<-1 \,\text{or}\,x>1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2 > 1\iff \lvert x\rvert >1$. Hence if $x<0$ and $x^2 > 1$ then $x<-1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$x - \frac{1}{x} < 0$$
$$\frac{x^2 - 1}{x} < 0 \text{ (common denominator)}$$
$$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x} < 0 \text{ (common denominator)}$$

Now you can make a chart:

[image]

And we get what we are looking for

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x^2-1}{x}$ may change sign iff it is zero, i.e., $x=\pm1$ or it is undefined, here $ x=0$.